# Follow-on to a question with too much scope

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, self-answer

I am really enjoying working through the problem [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188993/use-of-random-forests-for-variable-importance-as-preprocess-before-another-analy).  I could write a dozen articles for my question.  It is a good question, but it is extensible.  It addresses a big area.

Do you recommend that I:

- make a series of related questions of increasing sophistication but very narrow scope?
- make my own blog and stop placing this string of content on CV?
- Make an single vast answer with multiple parts?

Maybe I should turn it into "wiki".

- What is the ideal content for "community wiki"?
- If I convert it to wiki, can I make multiple, separated, answers to
  the same question?

D - none of the above:  Can you suggest something?

Comment: Are you asking about adding answers to an existing thread or about asking [a] new question[s]? This seems ambiguous / both-ish.

Comment: I'm asking what to do next.  The first part of the answer is complete, but the next part is just as long.  This would be pretty big.  The first part is ~5 pages.  The next part would likely be as long.

Comment: I just looked at the link. I think I see now. You asked a question & proffered an answer, both of which are long. But now you want to add more information & you're wondering if you should add more to your existing answer, or put together a series of Qs & As to present the material, since it will end up being so much. Is that the gist of it?

Comment: @gung - very much correct.  I think that I am working toward excessive and want to avoid that.  I will take direction and want to work within the guidelines of this community.

Comment: It's hard to comment on questions you _might_ write. Both question and answer were up-voted, so precedent is encouraging. Only writing similar questions (best done one at a time) will gauge the strength of interest.

Comment: @NickCox - I just don't want to get hated on for writing 100 pages of content.  I also don't want to get hated on for writing 10 articles in the same theme but with specific differences that are 5 pages long each.

Comment: Same advice: write one at a time. Or should you be writing journal papers about this work?